# React component not updating from props

Tags: reactjs

I have simplified the code to isolate and reproduce the issue, so it may not make sense in real implementations:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const obj = {
    objProp: true
};

export default class MyButtonContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyButton
                onClick={() => {obj.objProp = !obj.objProp;}}
                text={obj.objProp.toString()}
            />
        );
    }
}

class MyButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button
                onClick={this.props.onClick}
            >
                {this.props.text}
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

You can see that obj.objProp is assigned into MyButton.props.text, and it's value gets toggled when you click on an instance of MyButton. The value of obj.objProp does change as expected, but MyButton doesn't update and rerender.

My question is why is MyButton is not updating, and what is the proper way to implement such logic?

In addition, if the solution is to push obj into MyButtonContainer.state, why MyButton would of update if I have used Redux, which injects data only into props without changing the state?

Thanks :)

Comment: automatically it will not get rerendered,  you need to tell react to update it, either use forceUpdate (`this.forceUpdate();` inside click handler) or use state variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a state, You should not use variable this way, it needs to be on state and changing that state asynchronously.

Change your button container to this.

```
export default class MyButtonContainer extends Component {

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      objProp: true
    }
    this.onclick = this.onclick.bind(this);
  }

  onclick() {
    this.setState({ objProp: !this.state.objProp })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyButton
        onClick={() => { this.onclick() }}
        text={this.state.objProp.toString()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nppyer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So why when using Redux the component does update, although Redux only manipulate this.props without accessing the state?

Comment: Redux updates component you must be doing something wrong in that too.

Answer (score 1):

Use **state** to hold your `objProp`

React will rerender when there is `setstate` is called, it won't get rerendered automatically.

```
export default class MyButtonContainer extends Component {

      state = {
          objProp: true
      }

      onclick = () => {
        this.setState({ objProp: !this.state.objProp })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <MyButton
            onClick={() => { this.onclick() }}
            text={this.state.objProp.toString()}
          />
        );
      }
    }
}
```

Whenever there is something where you want the UI to change it should be either through its **State** or by **props** passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Both the given answers are right, if you want to re-render your component you must use this.setState. so there is two way to get your updated data in React Component.

1) put your object in to state and setState.
2) if you really dont want to use your object in state, you can do a workaround like take a variable i in your state and when assigning the data in your object just do this.setState({i+1}), so due to change in state will re-render your component although this is not good way to resolve it, because to re-render you must setState.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {i:0}
}
const obj = {
   objProp: true
};

export default class MyButtonContainer extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
          <MyButton
              onClick={() => {
                      obj.objProp = !obj.objProp ;
                      let {i} = this.state ; 
                      i = i + 1; 
                      this.setState(i)}}
                      text={obj.objProp.toString()}
          />
      );
   } 
}

class MyButton extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <button
              onClick={this.props.onClick}
          >
             {this.props.text}
          </button>
      )
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So why when I use Redux the component updates even if Redux is only manipulate this.props?

Comment: Yes because check your redux config you are updating state and passing it to all the component via props.
Redux create a state to store the data which you can pass via props in all the components. for more https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow

Comment: But according to my understanding, the state of the store is not related to the state of the components. The store state is just the current status of the object of the store, holding the data, as opposed to the component's state and props, which are responsible, among other things, to the representation of the components in the DOM, and they couldn't/shouldn't be manipulated directly (rather via setState, etc...). Do I got it right? are my assumptions are correct?